# Error in deploying to Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, windows-phone-8

I'm new to Windows Phone 8 development. While making the build for Windows phone 8 I am facing this following error particularly for Windows Phone 8 in unity.

```
Error building Player: Exception: Error: type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo` doesn't exist in target framework.
Error: type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo` doesn't exist in target framework.
Error: type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo` doesn't exist in target framework.
Error: type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo` doesn't exist in target framework.
Error: type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo` doesn't exist in target framework.
Error: type `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo` doesn't exist in target framework.
Error: type `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor` doesn't exist in target framework.
Error: type `System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor` doesn't exist in target framework.
```

Comment: That doesn't look like you put any effort in finding a solution on your own?!?

Comment: It is easy for you to say like this but the fact is I am trying from past three days. If you know the solution please tell me.

Comment: Usually, good SO questions follow these rules: http://sscce.org/ while this does not guarantee good answers, it encourages the readers to help you.

Comment: I already had tried all these tricks. That's why it took me three days to look at each and every thing properly once again. Any other solution??

Comment: Actually the problem with windows phone 8 is that it doesn't support some kind of .NET frameworks. The problem is that even on unity community nobody has responded to this problem yet and by surfing various sites related to this problem I am not able to find that what kind of framework is required for WP8. If you have any knowledge please tell me.

Comment: Have you any answers now?

Comment: My problem is solved by removing all the prime31 data from project mainli prime31.dll file from editor window. Anyone can do the same if his or her problem is not solved.